# How do I create the widget automatically on PyroCMS?

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, pyro, pyrocms

I'd like to develop a module as an event with registration form. An event is actually a page module with slight modification by adding some fields such registration form url. When the controller return a view, I'd like the controller to return a registration form widget along with the event info (article) and a google maps widget.

Imagine a widget class:

```
<?php
    class Registration_Form_Widget extends Widget{
       ......
   }
```

My question is:
Is it possible to create widget dynamically (I mean the creation of widget instance is dynamic (not the content) such using new Registration_Form_Widget  and bypass the parameter such the registration form url that has been stored to the database?

So far, I never see an example that show how to create widget instance dynamically with automatic increment id

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, widgets are created whenever you create em.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is obviously possible to achieve it with a bit of code.
There is no "magic function" to do that automatically, but you can look into the widget module  files to understand what is done when a user create a widget in the admin CP. And then you could reproduce the behaviour yourself.